# Error 000725 when using bearing to distance tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-000725

I try to use a tool called bearing distance to line, when i try to use this tool an error message appears on the screen:

> WARNING 000725 Output Feature Class: Dataset ....... already exists

and the new layer isn't created. the solution on the help which is to enable the ovewrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations in the toolbar does not help

Comment: why not just use a new filename?  is this being done from the toolbox or from a python script?

Comment: It would seem the output feature class dataset already exists.